# PHP old data still showing after POST

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post

The code below works, in that, it updates the database correctly.  However, after the post is completed the data on the page is old i.e. `$reader_busy[0]` is not updated even though it is driven by a SELECT query.

To force `$reader_busy[0]` to update properly on the users screen a refresh is required. This means the pages reloads after the post and then refreshes.

How do I get the page to display the correct data from the mysql without having to load the page twice?

Simplified version of my PHP code:

```
<?php 
$reader_key = 'jm2';
$reader_busy_query = "SELECT `BusyWithClient` " .
                     "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}assistant " .
                     "WHERE `Key`='" . $reader_key . "'";

$reader_busy = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $reader_busy_query ) );
$busy_with_client = $reader_busy[0];    

if(isset($_POST['toggle'])){
    $result = $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'assistant',
        array('BusyWithClient' => $busy_with_client), 
        array('Key' => $reader_key)                
    );

    // I want to remove / replace this line, and still see updated data. 
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=" . curPageURL() . "#instructions" . "'>";         
}
?>

<h1>
    <?php print_r('busy: ' . $reader_busy[0]); ?>
<h1>

<form  method="post" action="<?php echo curPageURL() . '#instructions'; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="toggle" value="toggle" >
</form>
```

Comment: Side-note: You are not using prepared statement properly. Follow the [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/#description) and use placeholders.

Comment: Now you set $read_key after Select, it should be before it. Also Mikey is right, use prepared sql statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flip the order of how you do things. Instead retrieving then updating, update before you retrieve.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['toggle'])) {
    $result = $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'assistant',
        array('BusyWithClient' => $busy_with_client), 
        array('Key' => $reader_key)                
    );   
}

$reader_busy_query = "SELECT `BusyWithClient` " .
                     "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}assistant " .
                     "WHERE `Key`='" . $reader_key . "'";

$reader_busy = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($reader_busy_query));
?>
```

Comment: I moved the if-statement before the SELECT operation, but am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Are you sure that you are updating then? Print out the value of `$result` after you update - see what value it gives.

Comment: You are right. It turns out that when I change the code order the update fails. The reason for this is that `$busy_with_client = $reader_busy[0];`  I forgot to show this in my question.  The question is now updated.

Comment: If I put `$reader_busy = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($reader_busy_query));` before the definition for `$busy_with_client` AND after the if-statement your suggestion works.

Comment: My original approach is usually the way to go: `UPDATE` then `SELECT`. The only problem is that the `UPDATE` depends on a value from your `SELECT`. The right way to do this is combine both statements by using an `UPDATE` with a [subquery](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) (look at **Subqueries with the UPDATE Statement**) then `SELECT`. Unfortunately, there's a small caveat as you will be doing a subquery using the same table that you are updating. It's tricky. But a simpler way to solve your problem though is to just do the another `SELECT` after the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to accomplish and that's looks impossible. Instead of refreshing page you can (should) make ajax request and update your page by refreshing only the page data that you need.

EDIT:

Because, you are trying to post to a page with ANCHOR, and browsers by there nature will try to find information on the page without refreshing it. Browser still sends information to post, so it updates in background, but not refreshes the page.

You should make post over ajax request and return data to field, or post it to another php file (without #hashtag).

PS - You will not get more answerers if you will downgrade every answers that didn't work for you :)

Comment: Could you explain more about why it is impossible?

Comment: I added more explanation